# Query parameters in Cosmos DB Graph-API

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

Are query parameters supported in the new Cosmos DB graph API?
For example in the query:

```
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, "g.V().has('name', 'john')");
```

Can I replace the hard-coded value 'john' with a query parameter as we could do in DocumentDB:

```
IQueryable<Book> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(
                collectionSelfLink,
                new SqlQuerySpec
        {
                    QueryText = "SELECT * FROM books b WHERE (b.Author.Name = @name)", 
                    Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection() 
            { 
                          new SqlParameter("@name", "Herman Melville")
                    }
        });
```

I am asking with security in mind. Or might there be other ways to defend against injections in Gremlin?

Answer (score -4):

Tinkerpop in general has a notion of `bindings`, which allow your to define your data separately from your gremlins scripts. An example using Java code can be found here: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java
 (search for bindings).

You can also use bindings through the Http endpoint for example by doing something like:

`curl http://localhost:8182 -d '{"gremlin": "g.V().has(key1, value1);", "bindings": {"key1": "name", "value1": "david"}}'`

You need to find out if the `client` in your query supports the bindings parameters, but it seems to me what you are looking for is a Tinkerpop compatible functionality.

Comment: That link in your answer points to docs that are really old and refer to TinkerPop 2.x which is not the version cosmosdb support (it's on 3.2.4 i believe). here's the related link to Apache TinkerPop 3.x docs: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-java